# Using lodash how I can keep a counter that later could used as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, loops, refactoring, lodash

here I have a typical for loop, where i is pass as a parameter later **.splice()**   My question is: How I can refactor this with lodash?

```
        for(var i =0; i< scope.liveBalls.length;i++){
            if(scope.liveBalls[i].bat === scope.ball.bat){
                scope.splicedBalls.push(scope.liveBalls.splice(i,1));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.each: Iterates over elements of collection invoking iteratee for each element. The iteratee is bound to thisArg and invoked with three arguments:
(value, index|key, collection). Iteratee functions may exit iteration early by explicitly returning false.

This means that you can refactor it like this:

```
_.each(scope.liveBalls, function (liveBall, index, liveBalls) {
  if(liveBall.bat === scope.ball.bat){
    scope.splicedBalls.push(liveBalls.splice(index, 1));
  }
});
```